# Google Form "Cannot convert [object Object] to (class)"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-sheets-macros

Morning everyone. I need your help.
I need to run this script to delete duplicates in a google reply form sheet

I copied this code into the spreadsheet because it gave me this error directly on the form TypeError: Could not call the "getSheetByName" method of null. (line 16, file "UPDATEcontact"):

```
function updateExisting(columnWithUniqueIdentifier,sheetTabName) {
  var dataFromColumnToMatch,lastColumn,lastRow,rowWithExistingUniqueValue,rowOfDataJustSaved,
      sh,ss,valueToSearchFor;

  // USER SETTINGS - if the values where not passed in to the function
  if (!columnWithUniqueIdentifier) {//If you are not passing in the column number
    columnWithUniqueIdentifier = 2;//Hard code column number if you want
  }

  if (!sheetTabName) {//The sheet tab name was not passed in to the function
    sheetTabName = "compleanno2020";//Hard code if needed
  }
  //end of user settings

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//Get the active spreadsheet - this code must be in a project bound to spreadsheet
  sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetTabName);


  lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  lastColumn = sh.getLastColumn();

  //Logger.log('lastRow: ' + lastRow)

  rowOfDataJustSaved = sh.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues();//Get the values that were just saved

  valueToSearchFor = rowOfDataJustSaved[0][columnWithUniqueIdentifier-1];
  //Logger.log('valueToSearchFor: ' + valueToSearchFor)

  dataFromColumnToMatch = sh.getRange(1, columnWithUniqueIdentifier, lastRow-1, 1).getValues();
  dataFromColumnToMatch = dataFromColumnToMatch.toString().split(",");
  //Logger.log('dataFromColumnToMatch: ' + dataFromColumnToMatch)

  rowWithExistingUniqueValue = dataFromColumnToMatch.indexOf(valueToSearchFor);
  //Logger.log('rowWithExistingUniqueValue: ' + rowWithExistingUniqueValue)

  if (rowWithExistingUniqueValue === -1) {//There is no existing data with the unique identifier
    return;
  }

  sh.getRange(rowWithExistingUniqueValue + 1, 1, 1, rowOfDataJustSaved[0].length).setValues(rowOfDataJustSaved);
  sh.deleteRow(lastRow);//delete the row that was at then end
}
```

Now I have this problem.

If I start the macro with a click everything works.

While if I associate the macro with a trigger I get this error message: Cannot convert [object Object] to (class). at updateExisting (NOduplicate: 29)

This is my spreadsheet:
[image]

function updateExisting:

```
function updateExisting() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
//      s = ss.getSheetByName(''),
      lastRow = s.getLastRow(),
      lastValues = s.getRange('A'+lastRow+':C'+lastRow).getValues(),
      name = lastValues[0][0],
      allNames = s.getRange('B2:B').getValues(), 
      row, len;

  // TRY AND FIND EXISTING NAME
  for (row = 0, len = allNames.length; row < len - 1; row++)
    if (allNames[row][0] == name) {
      // OVERWRITE OLD DATA
      s.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, row, 
lastValues.length).setValues([lastValues]);
      // DELETE THE LAST ROW
      s.deleteRow(lastRow);
      break;}
}
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you so much to all of you.

***Function updatExisting complete:***

```
function updateExisting() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      s = ss.getSheetByName('compleanno2020'),
      lastRow = s.getLastRow(),
      lastValues = s.getRange('A'+lastRow+':E'+lastRow).getValues(),
      name = lastValues[0][0],
      allNames = s.getRange('B2:B').getValues(), 
      row, len;

  // TRY AND FIND EXISTING NAME
  for (row = 0, len = allNames.length; row < len - 1; row++)
    if (allNames[row][0] == name) {
      // OVERWRITE OLD DATA
      s.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, row, 
lastValues.length).setValues([lastValues]);
      // DELETE THE LAST ROW
      s.deleteRow(lastRow);
      break;}
}


function updateExisting(columnWithUniqueIdentifier,sheetTabName) {
  var dataFromColumnToMatch,lastColumn,lastRow,rowWithExistingUniqueValue,rowOfDataJustSaved,
      sh,ss,valueToSearchFor;

  // USER SETTINGS - if the values where not passed in to the function
  if (!columnWithUniqueIdentifier) {//If you are not passing in the column number
    columnWithUniqueIdentifier = 2;//Hard code column number if you want
  }

  if (!sheetTabName) {//The sheet tab name was not passed in to the function
    sheetTabName = "compleanno2020";//Hard code if needed
  }
  //end of user settings

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vdHMZkDnE8Ua4XWcv45cmNkYPqqcK8THkRhVfMo0a78/edit#gid=1182430309');//Get the active spreadsheet - this code must be in a project bound to spreadsheet
  sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetTabName);


  lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  lastColumn = sh.getLastColumn();

  //Logger.log('lastRow: ' + lastRow)

  rowOfDataJustSaved = sh.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues();//Get the values that were just saved

  valueToSearchFor = rowOfDataJustSaved[0][columnWithUniqueIdentifier-1];
  //Logger.log('valueToSearchFor: ' + valueToSearchFor)

  dataFromColumnToMatch = sh.getRange(1, columnWithUniqueIdentifier, lastRow-1, 1).getValues();
  dataFromColumnToMatch = dataFromColumnToMatch.toString().split(",");
  //Logger.log('dataFromColumnToMatch: ' + dataFromColumnToMatch)

  rowWithExistingUniqueValue = dataFromColumnToMatch.indexOf(valueToSearchFor);
  //Logger.log('rowWithExistingUniqueValue: ' + rowWithExistingUniqueValue)

  if (rowWithExistingUniqueValue === -1) {//There is no existing data with the unique identifier
    return;
  }

  sh.getRange(rowWithExistingUniqueValue + 1, 1, 1, rowOfDataJustSaved[0].length).setValues(rowOfDataJustSaved);
  sh.deleteRow(lastRow);//delete the row that was at then end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getActiveSpreadsheet()` works only on some situations (using scripts that are bound to a Sheets document, etc). In many other cases, included some situations executing this on a trigger, this can result in an error. I suggest you replace this call for any of the following:

- [`open(file)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openfile)
- [`openById(id)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)
- [`openByUrl(url)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.
I tried to use this code but it always gives me the same error
`ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vdHMZkDnE8Ua4XWcv45cmNkYPqqcK8THkRhVfMo0a78/edit#gid=1182430309');//Get the active spreadsheet - this code must be in a project bound to spreadsheet
  sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetTabName); `

Can you send me an example code?

Comment: @MauroMancini Thanks for replying. Using this code you just commented, which is the exact error you get and where? Also, from which context are you running it (time-based trigger I presume?)?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm really inexperienced: D

When I start the script manually it works for me.
If I start it with a TRIGGER it always gives me this error:
ERROR: Cannot convert [object Object] to (class). (line 29, file "NOduplicate")

I set the trigger like this:

It runs during deployment: Head
Select the source of the event: from spreadsheet
Select the type of event: when the form is sent

Comment: @MauroMancini which value are you passing as `columnWithUniqueIdentifier`? Please make sure that it is a **number**. You can do that by logging its value, adding a line such as `Logger.log(typeof columnWithUniqueIdentifier)`. This line should print `Number`. As for the error message you describe, it seems to be that the argument passed to the function, in your case, is an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Comment: @ carlesgg97 I uploaded the image of my worksheet to the top of the post.
The value "columnWithUniqueIdentifier" that I am passing is the column 2 - email address that must be UNIQUE - no duplicate.

Or how can I do it?

Comment: @MauroMancini The issue comes when calling either of the following lines in your code: `valueToSearchFor = rowOfDataJustSaved[0][columnWithUniqueIdentifier-1];` or `dataFromColumnToMatch = sh.getRange(1, columnWithUniqueIdentifier, lastRow-1, 1).getValues();`. The parameters of both calls must be numbers - although `columnWithUniqueIdentifier` seems to be an object - which causes an issue. I am unsure as to what you are trying to do - could you describe what is inside the aforementioned variable (which kind of `object`?), or could you replace it in the lines of code I showed you?

Comment: thank you again for your valuable help.

The variable I need to check is column B where the email addresses of those who register are stored. What I want to avoid is that there are duplicates.

If column B is not possible - as it is not a number - you could avoid duplicates in column E where cell phone numbers are stored.

I hope I understand your question ;-)

Comment: Hey @MauroMancini, what I wanted to know is about the context of the function, rather. How/where/by which function (if applicable) is it being called? Hope it makes more sense now. Thanks

Comment: unfortunately my little experience and ability in the programming language does not make me understand what I have to answer. I answer your question .... I have no idea! ;-(

Is there anything I can see to help you give me a hand? : D

Comment: @MauroMancini What I mean is, there must be another function in your whole code that is calling your `updateExisting()` function. Is that correct? If so, what is the code of the function that calls `updateExisting()`?

Comment: thank you very much for your help and your patience.

Now I get it. I wrote the updateExisting function in the post written above. I thought they were two different and distinct codes.
So should I put it all together in the same macro?

Comment: @MauroMancini correct. If they are two distinct macros, you should also make sure that they have different names too in order to avoid any issue. Kindly let me know how would the final (merged?) macro look like so we may found the issue..

Comment: @ carlesgg97 I updated the main post with the complete function but I don't understand it much. I put it all together.
If I play the macro it works. Instead with the trigger associated with sending the form it gives me this error:

Cannot convert [object Object] to (class).
at updateExisting (NOduplicate: 50)

But surely something has to be changed in the function but I don't know how to do it !! :-(

Comment: Searching the web I read this about the error: "Cannot convert [object Object] to (class). (Line 50"

You can't pass parameters to the function from a trigger so start is undefined in the function when you run it with a trigger.

My macro works in manual mode while the active trigger triggers me this error! :-(